# IBM Notes 9 email issue. Automatic forward from my inbox to another recipient

Tags: java

IBM Notes 9
Vacation for 2 weeks
All incoming mail needs to be forwarded automatically to a colleague.
All incoming mail needs to also make it my inbox to be reviewed and followed up on when I return.

Here is what I found so far. Please explain steps if possible. I have no experience with Java and very limited experience with C over 5 years ago.

```
    import lotus.domino.*;
    import java.util.Vector;
    public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
      public void NotesMain() {
       try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
          // (Your code goes here) 
          Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
          DocumentCollection dc = 
              agentContext.getUnprocessedDocuments();
          Document reply;
          Vector sendTo;
          Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
          while (doc != null) {
            sendTo = doc.getAuthors();
            if (!doc.isSentByAgent()) {
              reply = doc.createReplyMessage(false);
              reply.replaceItemValue
              ("Subject", "Re: " + 
                 doc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
              reply.replaceItemValue(
                 "Body", "On vacation until 8/15\n");
              reply.send(sendTo);
              }
            doc = dc.getNextDocument(doc);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

The last time I was gone the admin set up forwarding but it skipped my inbox entirely. It got redirected to my colleague before hitting my inbox. I am not sure how he did this. I have found the code for setting up an autoreply to sender with a canned message about being on vacation. I want to edit this code to instead send the subject and body of the message to another recipient.

I expect to have incoming messages arrive in my inbox, my colleague's inbox, and he can reply to the original sender as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply set up a mail rule (Tools - Rules). You can turn it off upon your return.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I feel foolish for not knowing this was a possibility.